# How many binary vectors without consecutive of 11?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I have a question in exam and I did not solve it but I'm trying to solve it and still I don't know how to solve it. It is as following: how many vectors of size n without consecutive of 11s? for example if n=2, then we have the following list: {00, 01, 10}. If n=3, then we have all binary vectors of size 3 except these three {011, 110, 111}. If n=4, then we have have binary vectors of size except 8.

n ----> number of consecutive 11's

2 ----> 1

3 ----> 3

4 ----> 8

5 ----> 19

Comment: I believe this can be solved using two-state markov chains.

Comment: @Lovsovs I just did it by 3 states markov chains, but how can I take the sequence? I mean for n, how many vectors are there without consecutive 11? ( -->S1--->S2--->S3) in S1: if it has 0, then goes to S1, if it has 1, then it goes to S2. S2: if it has 0 goes to S1, if it has 1, goes to S3). In fact, we can eliminate last S3 and modify S2 to be: if it has 1, goes  to S2.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you any further, I'm not that familiar with Markov chains myself - I just recognized that they might be useful here :)

Comment: @Lovsovs your comment is helpful, I knew that we can get regular expression from markov chains, but still it doesn't give "exact" answer, for example regular expression says 1*, so it could be empty, or 1, 11, 111, etc. So, I'm assuming that in exam he wants exact answer. Any way, Thank you Lovsovs!

Comment: I believe that for $5$ there are 19 strings containing $11$, not $18$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a binary string (vector) $c_1 \cdots c_n c_{n + 1}$ contains no (consecutive) substring $11$, then the same is true for the truncated substring $c_1 \cdots c_n$.

Now, given a string $c_1 \cdots c_n$, if $c_n = 0$, there are two strings, namely $c_1 \cdots c_{n - 1} 0 0$ and $c_1 \cdots c_{n - 1} 0 1$ not containing $11$ that truncate to that string, and if $c_n = 1$, there is only string, namely $c_1 \cdots 1 0 $ that truncates to that string.

This description immediately furnishes a recurrence relation: Let $a_n$ be the number of strings of length $n$ not containing $11$ and ending in $0$, and $b_n$ be the number of strings of length $n$ not containing $11$ and ending in $1$, so that $S_n := a_n + b_n$ is the total number of strings of length $n$ not containing $11$. Then, $a_n, b_n$ satisfy
$$\left\{\begin{align}
a_{n + 1} &= a_n + b_n = S_n\\
b_{n + 1} &= a_n
\end{align}\right. .$$
Now, reindexing the first equation and substituting in the second gives
$$b_{n + 1} = a_{n - 1} + b_{n - 1} = S_{n - 1},$$ and then adding this equation to the first equation above gives that $S_{n + 1} = a_{n + 1} + b_{n - 1}$ satisfies
$$S_{n + 1} = S_n + S_{n - 1},$$ which is the usual Fibonacci recurrence relation. Using the $S_0 = 1$, $S_1 = 2$ gives that $S_n = F_{n + 2}$, where $F_n$ is the usual Fibonacci sequence (indexed so that $F_0 = 0$, $F_1 = 1$). So, the sequence $S_n$ is $1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, \ldots$, and can be written explicitly by shifting an index in [Binet's Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html):
$$S_n = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left(\phi^{n + 2} - (-\phi)^{-(n + 2)} \right).$$
For $n \geq 0$, we have $\left\vert \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(-\phi)^{-(n + 2)}\right\vert < \frac{1}{2}$, we can write $S_n$ compactly as
$$S_n = \left[\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \phi^{n + 2} \right],$$
where $[x]$ denotes the integer nearest $x$.

Since there are $2^n$ strings of length $n$, the number of strings of length $n$ containing $11$ is $2^n - S_n$, which gives the sequence
$$0, 0, 1, 3, 8, 19, \ldots$$
indicated in the question.

Comment: Really great answer. I want to clarify my understanding. What is the size of $c_i$? I'm assuming it means string of size 2 since we have either 10 or 00 in $a_n$ and 01 in $b_n$. Also, you write that $a_{n+1} = a_n + b_n = S_n$  why not taking for example: $a_{n+1} = a_n + a_n = S_n$ since $a_n$ ends with 0.

Comment: Here $c_i$ is just a bit, $0$ or $1$, and $c_1 \cdots c_n$ is an $n$-bit string. As for the formula for $a_{n + 1}$, that quantity is the number of strings of length $n + 1$ not containing $11$ and ending in $0$. Any such string can be produced by adding a $0$ to a string of length $n$ and not containing $11$, and there, by definition, $S_n$ of those, $a_n$ of which end in $0$ and $b_n$ of which end in $1$.

Answer (score 0):

An inductive argument derives the number of adminissible bit sequence for n+1:

[image]

**Example:**
For $n=2$, there are two sequences with end digit $..0$ and one sequence with end digit $..1$. All three sequences may be extended by appending a $0$. But only the two sequences $..0$ may be extended by appending a $1$.